# Making a Venn diagram comparing column combinations between two data frames

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I am having trouble solving this problem:

I have two data frames, each with two columns called `c("miRNAs", "Targets")`. Each data frame is a combination of predicted microRNAs and their target from different programs. I am trying to plot a Venn diagram that shows the intersection of these two predictions but I am failing at the last step. I can detect similarities and differences but I can't plot the Venn diagram.

The data frames look like this:

```
> dput(test_a)
structure(list(miRNA = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L
), .Label = c("miR-10", "miR-300", "miR-8", "miR-9"), class = "factor"), 
    Target = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
    "AA", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

> dput(test_b)
structure(list(miRNA = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L
), .Label = c("", "miR-10", "miR-12", "miR-9"), class = "factor"), 
    Target = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "A", "B", "C", "D", "Y"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

#present in both dataframes
both_test_ab<- intersect(test_a, test_b)

   miRNA Target
1 miR-10      A
2 miR-10      B
3 miR-10      C
#present only in a 
only1  <- setdiff(test_a, test_b)
    miRNA Target
1   miR-9      A
2   miR-8      D
3 miR-300     AA

#present only in b 
only2  <- setdiff(test_b,test_a )
 miRNA Target
1  miR-9      Y
2 miR-12      D

#Venn diagram (PROBLEM)
vp  <- venn.diagram(
x = list(test_a, test_b), col=c("#440154ff", '#21908dff'),
fill = c(alpha("#440154ff",0.3), alpha('#21908dff',0.3)),
category.names = c("seed" , "miranda"),
filename = NULL, cat.pos = 1)
```

Could anyone tell me why I can't draw the Venn diagram and how to solve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong data type. The function `venn.diagram()` requires a list of **vectors**. However, `test_a` and `test_b` are data frames.

I converted `test_a` and `test_b` to vectors, and it worked. See below.

```
# Convert to vectors
test_a_vector <- as.vector(unlist(test_a))
test_b_vector <- as.vector(unlist(test_b))

# Create Venn Diagram 
venn.diagram(
  x = list(test_a_vector, test_b_vector), col=c("#440154ff", '#21908dff'),
  category.names = c("seed" , "miranda " ), fill = c(alpha("#440154ff",0.3), alpha('#21908dff',0.3)),
  filename = '#Ven_Test.tiff',
  output=TRUE, cat.pos = 1)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I assume it was something like that due to the fact that they were data frames but couldn't solve it. Thanks a lot!!!!